# How can you set Backbone.Validation validations on a model attribute that contains an object?

Tags: validation, backbone.js

I have a model that has a password attribute.  The password attribute in the request payload is like so:

```
loginId: "yourId",
password: {password: yourpassword}
```

How can I set validation on this using Backbone.validation?

I was trying to do:

```
validation: {
   loginId: {
       required: true,
       msg: 'Please Enter a Login ID.'
    },
   password: {
       required: true,
       msg: 'Please Enter a Password.' 
   }
}
```

However, my password always fails validation.  I figure this is because the code is not able to check the password attribute inside the hash of the password attribute.  Do you know how I could form this validation to work correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using a custom validation function inside the model:

```
validation: {
    loginId: {
      required: true,
      msg: 'Please Enter a Login ID.'
    },
    password: function(value, attr, computedState) {
      if(!value || !value.get('password')) {
          return 'Please enter a password.';
      }
    {
},
default: function(){
    return {
        "password" : new Backbone.Model(),
    }; 
},
```

I had to specify a default model, since the password attribute on the model is actually a password model on the server, so you need to give a blank model for starters.  I also had to make sure the bindings in my view were set correctly.